# Register rest field authentication with REST API

Tags: rest-api, authentication, nonce

I'm trying to add some user meta information to the existing `wp/v2/users` REST endpoint. However, it looks like additional authentication is required, i.e. I get this (output in comments):

```
    error_log( is_user_logged_in() ); // true
    register_rest_field( 'user',
        'is_logged_in',
        array(
            'get_callback' => function () {
                return is_user_logged_in(); // false
            },
        )
    );
```

(so it doesn't seem possible to get actual user meta in the new field I registered).

Firstly: please correct me if I'm wrong on this point because it would make things much easier.

However, assuming additional authentication is required: I tried just setting _wpnonce to the nonce I got when logged in, and got back a 403. I simply want to be able to send any user who is logged in their own user data in JSON format. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You should read [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) about authentication with the REST API.

Comment: I did, hence the question (see last paragraph). I need to be able to output this info without additional HTTP headers that aren't in GET, and when trying to set GET _wpnonce it didn't work—I probably didn't get the right nonce. This is where my understanding seems to end.

Comment: The documentation shows you how to get the proper nonce. You can enqueue the `'wp-api'` script and the nonce will be available via `wpApiSettings.nonce`. If you want to do it on your own, use `wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )` to create the nonce.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad API design to return different structure based on "external data" not passed in the request itself.

Either construct different API for logged in users and use a different end point for it, or return a "filler" when the user do not have permission to access the data.

(and it is always a bad idea to make modifications to the official rest API as you might create incompatibilities with other users of it, so at least be careful use prefixes etc)